# Turn cell into False based another row/column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table of boolean values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': [True, False, False, True], 
                        'val2': [False, True, False, True], 
                        'val3': [True, True, False, True], 
                        'val4': [True, False, True, False], 
                        'val5': [True, True, False, False],
                        'val6': [False, False, True, True]},
                        index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='index'))
```

| index | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | False | True | True | True | False |
| 2 | False | True | True | False | True | False |
| 3 | False | False | False | True | False | True |
| 4 | True | True | True | False | False | True |

I also have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {'val1': ['val2', 'val3'], 'val4': ['val5', 'val6']}
```

How do I change the table so for every key column in `dict`, if that row has a `True` value, the value columns turn to `False`?

| index | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | **False** | **False** | True | **False** | **False** |
| 2 | False | True | True | False | True | False |
| 3 | False | False | False | True | False | **False** |
| 4 | True | **False** | **False** | False | False | True |

For example, since `val1` is `True` at index 1, `val2` and `val3` turned to `False`

I'm doing something like this:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    if df[k] == True:
        df[v] = False
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Why did `val6` in row 3 turn to `False`?

Comment: Use `df.where()`

Comment: ```val6``` in row 3 turned to ```False``` because ```val4``` is ```True``` for that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `if` with Series, which is only meant for scalar boolean check. Use conditional update with boolean indexing instead:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    df.loc[df[k], v] = False  # update columns v where df[k] is True

df
        val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6
index                                          
1       True  False  False   True  False  False
2      False   True   True  False   True  False
3      False  False  False   True  False  False
4       True  False  False  False  False   True
```